# Angular form is Invalid when Autofill on mobile devices

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I've gone through all the examples already avilable on stackoverflow, but none seems to be working for my case.

I've two fields, `username` & `password`, when user autofill's `Login button` is still disabled.

On Desktop: After autofilling if I click anywere on the page, `Login` button get's ebabled.

On Mobile Devices: After autofilling, I need to delete any words and refill it again to enable the `Login button`.

Below is what I tried,

Adding a click event to body tag, not working

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', ()=> { console.log('body Event clicked') });
  }
```

Check for value changes when form is changed, But this breaking the functionality after autofilling, this function is running infinite times and makes browser to hangup.

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {

   if(this.loginForm.get('loginId').value !== '' && this.loginForm.get('password').value !== '') {
    this.store.dispatch(new FormChanged({ isFormValid: true }));
    console.log('Login Form Value', this.loginForm.value);

   }
```

Login Form code:

```
  setUpForm() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      loginId: ['', [Validators.required, this.loginUtilService.validateFbNumberOrEmail]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.cService.CONSTANTS.PATTERNS.ROBUSTPASSWORD)]],
    });
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.loginForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.onFormChanges())
    );
  }

  onFormChanges() {
    console.log('onFormChanges isFormValid', this.loginForm.valid);
    this.store.dispatch(new FormChanged({ isFormValid: this.loginForm.valid }));
  }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Please share how you have defined `loginForm`

Comment: I've updated my code

Comment: You can try to force detecting the changes with changedetectorref. See here: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges

Comment: I think the reason that this is failing is because one of the Validators `this.loginUtilService.validateFbNumberOrEmail` OR `Validators.pattern(this.cService.CONSTANTS.PATTERNS.ROBUSTPASSWORD)` is failing, check the autofilled values if they satify this validations

Comment: it's saticifics the pattern.

Comment: can you share the html?